# Rolling join with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Someone tweeted the other day that `dplyr` now supports inequality joins ("rolling joins") but the version on CRAN does not mention that.  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I would ask the tweet author. There's nothing in the dplyr github that I can see to suggest that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such single function for this in dplyr but assuming that what you are referring to is this complex join shown in SQL which for any row i computes the mean demand of those rows whose time points are between `Time[i]-2` and `Time[i]`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.Time, a.demand demand, avg(b.demand) mean_demand 
       from BOD a join BOD b on b.Time between a.Time - 2 and a.Time
       group by a.Time")
```

then this could be done in dplyr and tidyr like this (although it does have the significant disadvantage that it forms the full n x n cross join and then filters it down).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
BOD %>% 
    expand(., ., .) %>% 
    group_by(Time, demand) %>% 
    filter(Time1 <= Time & Time1 >= Time-2) %>% 
    summarize(mean_demand = mean(demand1)) %>%
    ungroup
```

It could also be done with `zoo::rollapplyr` like this.  Here `Avg` is a function which takes a vector of row numbers `ix` and returns the mean of `demand` for those input rows whose times are at least `max(Time[ix])-2`.   We `rollapplyr` over the row numbers using that function.

```
library(zoo)
Avg <- function(ix) with(BOD[ix, ], mean(demand[Time >= max(Time) - 2]))
transform(BOD, Avg = rollapplyr(1:nrow(BOD), 3, Avg, partial = TRUE))
```

or if you just want the most recent 3 rows regardless of their times then it is even easier:

```
transform(BOD, Avg = rollapplyr(demand, 3, mean, partial = TRUE))
```

Also see [this link](https://r-norberg.blogspot.ca/2016/06/understanding-datatable-rolling-joins.html) for rolling joins in data.table.

Comment: For the non-tidyverse approach I much prefer `data.table` which I've found to be elegant and blazing fast for complete rolling joins.  E.g.:http://data.vanderbilt.edu/fh/attach/rolljoin.r

Comment: I do find that the SQL approach has greater clarity for rolling joins.  For example, compare clarity of the code for `d` in your link to this SQL code: `d <- sqldf("select d1.*, d2.pos from d2 left join d1 on d1.x = d2.x and d2.pos between d1.start and d1.end")` In addition, the SQL code can handle larger inputs since one can specify that the computation be done out of memory.

Comment: Great answer. Could you point out what the dots in expand(., ., .)  do here? I tried looking up documentation, couldnt figure it out

Comment: dot refers to the input, in this case `BOD`, so it is the same as `expand(BOD, BOD, BOD)` .

Answer (score 3):

Rolling joins are now supported in `dplyr 1.1.0` with `join_by`.

Use `following` and `preceding` to find observations resp. directly after and directly before a particular observation/date. Use `>=`, `>`, `<=`, `<` to match more than one observation (preceding or following).

```r
sales <- tibble(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
                sale_date = as.Date(c("2018-12-31", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-01")))

promos <- tibble(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L),
                 promo_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-02")))

left_join(sales, promos, join_by(id, following(sale_date, promo_date)))
#left_join(sales, promos, join_by(id, sale_date <= promo_date))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id sale_date  promo_date
  <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2018-12-31 2019-01-01
2     1 2019-01-02 2019-01-05
3     1 2019-01-05 2019-01-05
4     2 2019-01-04 NA        
5     2 2019-01-01 2019-01-02

left_join(sales, promos, join_by(id, sale_date <= promo_date))
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     id sale_date  promo_date
  <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2018-12-31 2019-01-01
2     1 2018-12-31 2019-01-05
3     1 2019-01-02 2019-01-05
4     1 2019-01-05 2019-01-05
5     2 2019-01-04 NA        
6     2 2019-01-01 2019-01-02

left_join(sales, promos, join_by(id, preceding(sale_date, promo_date)))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id sale_date  promo_date
  <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2018-12-31 NA        
2     1 2019-01-02 2019-01-01
3     1 2019-01-05 2019-01-05
4     2 2019-01-04 2019-01-02
5     2 2019-01-01 NA
```

Comment: Compared with `data.table`, the tidyverse continues to have to invent a myriad of separate functions to accomplish tasks.

Comment: It supposedly gives more flexibility (see e.g. my edit)