# How to regularize a time series data frame at specific interval

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a time series dataframe:

```
structure(list(Date_Time = structure(c(1685975396, 1685975406, 
1685975416, 1685975426, 1685975436, 1685975446, 1685975457, 1685975467, 
1685975477, 1685975487, 1685975497, 1685975507), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Heat Capacity` = c(-209L, 
-209L, -203L, -202L, -197L, -196L, -191L, -185L, -185L, -184L, 
-184L, -185L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm trying to regularize the data at 15min interval

**For example:**

if the Date_Time column ranges  from 14:26 to 15:26

I want the Date_Time to be summarised  like: 14:30, 14:45, 15:00 where

at each time stamps like 14:30 the **Heat Capacity value** should have just previous minute value.
Example:

```
Time    Heat_capacity
14:30    value at 14:29
```

**Sample Data and Expected Output:**

So the Heat Capacity value at 6/5/2023 2:30pm is value at 2:29th minute

[image]

Comment: could you include the expected table results?

Comment: The `Date_Time` column only ranges from `14:29:56` to `14:31:47`. Are you looking to adjust the times or ????

Comment: Maybe group_by(interval = lubridate::ceiling_date(Date_Time, “15 minutes”) |> summarize(‘Heat Capacity’ = last(‘Heat Capacity’)?

Comment: @Onyambu I hope the new example give you an idea

Comment: "I want the Date_Time to be summarised like: 14:30, 14:45, 15:00 " what about "15:15"? and "15:30"?

Comment: @jan-glx. Yes that too. I just didn't add the whole dataframe in the question. When I try to run it worked as I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to resample your timeseries with an  last observation carried forward (LOCF) operation. This can be done efficiently using [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) with a `roll=+Inf` join. (`dt[dt_regular, on = "Date_Time", roll=+Inf]` , where `dt` is your data and `dt_regular` is a data.table with a single Date_Time column with 15 minute intervalls).

Considering your example:

```r
library(data.table)
df
#>              Date_Time Heat Capacity
#> 1  2023-06-05 14:29:56          -209
#> 2  2023-06-05 14:30:06          -209
#> 3  2023-06-05 14:30:16          -203
#> 4  2023-06-05 14:30:26          -202
#> 5  2023-06-05 14:30:36          -197
#> 6  2023-06-05 14:30:46          -196
#> 7  2023-06-05 14:30:57          -191
#> 8  2023-06-05 14:31:07          -185
#> 9  2023-06-05 14:31:17          -185
#> 10 2023-06-05 14:31:27          -184
#> 11 2023-06-05 14:31:37          -184
#> 12 2023-06-05 14:31:47          -185
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# get time range of interested  rounded to full hours with a an hour of buffer
date_range <- dt[,round(range(Date_Time)+c(-60*60, 60*60) , unit="hours")]
# create 15-minute-spaced full hour aligned regular grid of time range of interest
df_regular <- data.table(Date_Time = do.call(seq, c(as.list(date_range), "15 min")))
# LOCF join into actual data ( dropping left side off buffer with `nomatch=NULL`)
dt[df_regular, ,on = "Date_Time", roll = +15*60, nomatch=NULL]
#>              Date_Time Heat Capacity
#>                 <POSc>         <int>
#> 1: 2023-06-05 14:30:00          -209
#> 2: 2023-06-05 14:45:00          -185
```

Here we are allowing a maximum carry forward of 15 min to get rid of buffer time on the right. This might lead to a  drop of grid time points if there is no measurement in the 15 min before. In case this does not suffice your needs you need to be more specific about the time range that you want to handle or how to deal with those cases.

However, you might want to prefer to work directly with your unequally spaced time points using eg. [`fable`](https://github.com/tidyverts/fable) or use averaging or interpolation instead.

Comment: can you give me a code example

Comment: @golem there you go. will delete this comment in a bit

Comment: Thanks @jan-glx It worked just like wanted. How can I learn more about data.table package. Also one more question '" Can this same thing be done in dplyr"?

Comment: Apparently yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072295/rolling-join-with-dplyr
https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/01/dplyr-1-1-0-joins/#rolling-joins , but I rarely use the tidyverse since data.table gives me almost everything in one line of code that wont give a warning next year and often so much faster. The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) is a good start i believe. If you don't like to read there is [this data.table cheat sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/datatable.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `round_date` from the lubridate package:

```
lubridate::round_date(Date_Time, "15 minutes")
```

rounds time to full 15 minutes. The full workflow with `dplyr` could look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
my Data %>% 
  mutate(Date_Time2 = lubridate::round_date(Date_Time, "15 minutes")) %>%
  group_by(Date_Time2) %>%
  mutate(
    HC = last(`Heat Capacity`)
  )
```

Comment: its not result I'm expecting. At 15:30 it shows different value not the value at previous minute which will 15:29

Comment: floor_date or ceiling_date are probably more what you're looking for, since they will put observations in say, minute 2 and minute 14 into the same group.